# Using Socket Keep Alive in EventMachine

Tags: ruby, tcp

I have an EventMachine that accepts TCP connections.  These connections close automatically after about 10 minutes of inactivity, which is bad for me.  I need them to stay open.  I think I need to set the KEEPALIVE socket option on the connections but I'm having a little trouble figuring out the syntax.

Here is what I tried, but that didn't fix anything:

```
class Connection < EventMachine::Connection
    def initialize
      set_sock_opt Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_KEEPALIVE, true
    end
```

For reference, here is my main EventMachine loop:

```
  EventMachine::run do
    EventMachine::start_server(host, port, Connection)
  end
```